# Are there any notable cricketing baseballers or baseball-playing cricketers?

Tags: cricket, baseball, history

Are there any attempts (in history or today) of top-level baseball players (cricketers) having a shot at "higher-level" cricket (baseball) (and perhaps succeeding in some sort of way)? I do not mean demonstration or recreational games and the like, but rather real higher-level competitions.

Comment: I think you forgot about john davison cricketer from canada who also played baseball in USA

Comment: Wikipedia has [several people](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Australian+cricketers%22+%22Australian+baseball+players%22+site:wikipedia.org) listed in both categories: *Australian cricketers* and *Australian baseball players*.

Comment: @KeerthiKumar Could you please provide references for John Davison's _baseball_ career? At what level did he play baseball?

Comment: Alan Border insists that he was a better baseball player than cricketer: Sebel Townhouse Bar
1989.Septic.

Comment: This is not a complete answer. Is there any reference to support this?

Comment: Yes, met AB STH, I was a yank that knew a bit about cricket, playing with a wandering village side in the U.K. Didn't really know about AB before this, but he believed he was a better baseball player than cricketer,. The American major league baseball clubs were not scouting
the Antipodes in the 1980's. In the 1990's till today there are a lot of Skippy's playing
both minor and major league baseball in America, mostly pitchers.

Answer (score 5):

Australian cricketer [Bill Ponsford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Ponsford) was considered [a good baseball player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Ponsford#Baseball) in his country.

Answer (score 3):

Three Australian cricket captains also played baseball for the [Mosman Baseball club](http://www.mosman.baseball.com.au/default.asp?Page=7857): **Richie Benaud**, **Allan Border** and **Ian Chappell**. The club also [lists](http://www.mosman.baseball.com.au/default.asp?Page=7857) the following test cricketers who played for them:

- Ian Craig
- Neil Harvey
- Graham Hole
- Gordon F Rorke
- David Sincock

Comment: That's fascinating! The cricket is obviously top level, but what about their baseball? My browsing on the Mosman website doesn't reveal "serious" competition. Were they involved in a certain level of league at the times?

Answer (score 0):

Back in the 19th century, teams of professional baseball stars used to go on tours to England and overseas and play cricket against the locals.  They won most of the time.